# Don't rely on rov for general blessings, but do for tevila

Tags: halacha, blessing, gentiles, tevilas-keilim-dipping

The **Mishnah Berurah** ([215:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.215.20)) brings from the **Chayei Adam** (Kelal 5) and **Pri Megadim** (Pesicha LeHilchos Berachos) that even if there's *sfek sfeka* (a double doubt) telling you **to make** a blessing, we don't rely on it to allow you to make a blessing.

In contrast, I heard in a class that there are *poskim* who hold that if the majority of factories in a country are owned by non Jews, you can rely on *rov* for *tevilas keilim* and make a blessing. This includes **Rav Moshe** ([OC 3:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14676&st=&pgnum=299)).

Are the opinions who say this by *tevilas keilim* disagreeing with what the **Mishnah Berurah** brings? Or is there some distinction I'm unaware of.

I ask because [there are those that say](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A7-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%90-%D7%90) (such as Teshuvos HaRashba 1:401) that *sfek sfeika* works through *rov*, by looking at the majority of possible outcomes. Not everyone agrees. So would that be the distinction? It might be that the **Mishnah Berurah** doesn't distinguish, as in the **Beur Halacha** ([60:4 s.v. וכן הלכה](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.60.4.4)) he explains that even though the halacha is *mitzvos* need *kavana* (which I'm understanding because of *rov*, but you could argue), for blessings we still need to be cautious for the (minority) opinions that *mitzvos* don't need *kavana*.

Comment: The Iggerot Moshe's reason seems strange to me. He says that in a case of doubt you don't make a blessing, but if it comes from Europe where most factories belong to non-Jews you can make the blessing. So what's the case of doubt? Don't American factories also mostly belong to non-Jews?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89685/759 @ba the case of doubt is where for some reason there is a doubt (mixed it up with a jews dish, whatever). Parush from rov is not a doubt.

Comment: @robev even rashba doesn't say the mutar opinions are poreish from rov. You're comparing apples and oranges. No one would say not to say a blessing on shechting if you only cut most of the neck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98084/discussion-between-b-a-and-double-aa).

Comment: The mishna berurah is talking about a safek le'halachah and Reb Moshe is talking about a safek metzius?